# Cannot convert value of type '(CMDeviceMotion?, NSError?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'CMDeviceMotionH

Tags: ios, swift

I recently upgraded my xcode. i am currently using 9.2
I am using CMMotionManger and this error shows in new version. I tried solving it but could not find the solution.

```
func startCameraTracking() {
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0


        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(OperationQueue.main) {
            [weak self](data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: NSError?) in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            let attitude: CMAttitude = data.attitude
            self?.cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(Float(attitude.roll + M_PI/2.0), -Float(attitude.yaw), -Float(attitude.pitch))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please correct title.

Comment: I would suggest that you look up the documentation of it. The closure obviously expects another type instead of `CMDeviceMotion`, but which one is cut off in the title of this post

Comment: Look up [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager/1616048-startdevicemotionupdates) and the referenced `CMDeviceMotionHandler` type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Michael, you should better check the latest reference:

(`startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(_: withHandler:)` is renamed to `startDeviceMotionUpdates(to:withHandler:)`.)

### [`startDeviceMotionUpdates(to:withHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager/1616048-startdevicemotionupdates)

> #### Declaration
>
> ```
> func startDeviceMotionUpdates(to queue: OperationQueue, 
>                   withHandler handler: @escaping CMDeviceMotionHandler)
> ```

---

### [`CMDeviceMotionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmdevicemotionhandler)

> #### Declaration
>
> ```
> typealias CMDeviceMotionHandler = (CMDeviceMotion?, Error?) -> Void
> ```

---

For the second parameter of `startDeviceMotionUpdates(to:withHandler:)`, you need to pass a closure taking `CMDeviceMotion?` and `Error?`, not `NSError?`:

```
func startCameraTracking() {
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0

    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) {
        [weak self](data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        let attitude: CMAttitude = data.attitude
        self?.cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(Float(attitude.roll + .pi/2.0), -Float(attitude.yaw), -Float(attitude.pitch))
    }
}
```